# SVN Integration Plugin in IntelliJ does not support Check Directory Status?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn

Any idea why does the "SVN Integration" plugin in IntelliJ does not support "check directory status" command? Similar to "check for modifications" command supported by Tortoise SVN client?

Answer (score 5):

IDEA asks status in background by itself, and it is shown in Changes | Local.

Also the color of the directory name in Project view is blue, if the directory was moved/renamed, or properties had changed in it.

If you mean the status of the directory recursively - well, you can turn on by folder grouping in Changes | Local